# How to get the number of running, sleeping, stopped, and zombie processes in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Unix, Linux, and shell scripting.
I need to know how to find the number of running, sleeping, stopped, and zombie processes.

I think I found some ways to find the number of running processes:

```
ps -ef | wc -l
ps r | wc -l
```

But I'm not sure which is better, or if either is a good way to do this.

When it comes to sleeping, stopped, and zombie though, I have no clue where to go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you have less installed to read man pages. Open `man ps` and search for "PROCESS STATE CODES" with `\PROCESS STATE CODES`. That should get you started.

Comment: What shell is it that you are running/using? bash?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, use `top` in one-shot mode:

```
$ top -bn1 | grep zombie
Tasks:  96 total,   1 running,  90 sleeping,   5 stopped,   0 zombie
```

You can then use `awk` to pull out the individual numbers, if that's more palatable:

```
$ top -bn1 | grep zombie | awk '{print $4" "$6" "$8" "$10}'
1 90 5 0
```

If you happen to have a process named "zombie" this recipe will run afoul. You might want to replace `grep zombie` with `sed -n 2p`.