# How to get output of top command

Tags: linux, bash, process, command, output

I'm wondering how to get the output of the 'top' command. I'm looking to obtain the number of currently running processes.

I tried putting it to a text file and got garbage. I'm unsure on how to approach this. My assignment is to determine the number of processes considered by the short-term scheduler for process allocation (processes currently ready to run) at any given time.

Comment: `top` is a primarily an interactive command. `ps` is better for scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use top in batch mode:

```
top -bn1 > output.txt
```

See also this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32463811/2908724).

Comment: @ChrisMontanaro True that.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than parsing top you could count the lines in the process list:

```
ps -ef | wc -l
```